# Rails UJS: Preventing the event from propagating using 'ajax:before'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am confused by how `ajax:before` works when using [rails/jquery-ujs.](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)

1. Does it wait for any given function in the `ajax:before` to complete before proceeding?
2. How do I completely cancel the event in jQuery if it fails some condition? (I do not seem to have a pointer to the event)

--

Update: I tried this, which normally works, but not now. =|

```
.bind('ajax:before', function(evt){
    evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
   } )
 //also tried preventDefault, stopPropagation, etc
```

Comment: are you using this? https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for asking! i am using that file indeed. i updated the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I answered my own question.  "return false" in the ajax:before will cancel the action