# Rails 4: form remote custom ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form where users can paste an URL for an image. And when the user submits the form I want to make an ajax GET request first which downloads the image client-side and checks it before proceeding for security purposes.

My problem ist that the remote form already does an ajax request and I can only access it with those before and complete bindings. But actually I need to chain them. When the image check is done, proceed with the POST ajax request from the form.

How can I do this?

(Sry, I'm using Slim)

```
= form_for @post, html: { class: "form-horizontal", role: "form" }, remote: true  do |f|
  .form-group
    = f.label :author, "Name", class: "col-xs-1 control-label"
    .col-xs-11
        = f.text_field :author, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Name"
  .form-group
    = f.label :title, "Titel", class: "col-xs-1 control-label"
    .col-xs-11
        = f.text_field :title, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Titel"
  .form-group
    = f.label :text, "URL", class: "col-xs-1 control-label"
    .col-xs-11
        = f.url_field :text, class: "form-control", placeholder: "http://"


  .form-group
    .col-xs-offset-1.col-xs-11
      = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-default"
```

Comment: With just javascript, this would be easy. But i have no idea what you have going on there with ror. you would just preload the image, check it's height/width to make sure it's not 0x0, do whatever additional checks you want, then post your form data.

Comment: yup it would be indeed... but rails has this automatic ajax request for remote forms and links. My problem is that I don't quite know how to build a form in rails with a custom ajax request like explained above and send the right result to my controlle create action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try listening on the `ajax:before` or `ajax:beforeSend` events that the UJS adapter for rails provides.

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

According to the documentation, if you 'stop' those events using `return false`, the remote form request should never go through. So you can, via ajax, download the image in one of those events before the form is submitted and do your check there.

Comment: event.stopPropagation() didn't stop the request :( $('#new_post').bind('ajax:beforeSend', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
 });

Comment: How about `return false`? Seems to work as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366777/rails-ujs-preventing-the-event-from-propagating-using-ajaxbefore

Comment: `return false` stops the request from going through as expected on a new Rails 4.0.0 app.